# Efficient polling of a website in the background? (Firefox Addon SDK)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, html-parsing, firefox-addon-sdk, polling

Reading up on the SDK documentations... I found these:

## Option 1: Request

The [request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) API . I get a HTML string as a response. However to parse the HTML and extract the relevant table data that I need, I would have to create a DOM element somewhere. Something like [this HTML to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM#Using_a_hidden_browser_element_to_parse_HTML_to_a_window.27s_DOM%20this).

But the addon-sdk guidelines say to open remote content on a content-script. So, why the request module?

## Option 2: Page-worker

The page-worker API allows to load pages permanently in the background. For polling puposes, I can repeatedly create a pageworker and destroy it after extracting the required data after certain periods of time.

So, which is a better option? Request or Page-worker? And why should I prefer one over the other?
Page-worker creates a document object every time I poll the website. Isn't it a browser intensive task to do this create-DOM-destroy-DOM task repeatedly?

Also, what about location.reload() in this context?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [`page-worker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker).

You can either create a new `page-worker` for each "poll" and destroy the old one when it's no longer needed, for refresh a single `page-worker` using `PageWorker(/*...*/).contentURL = "https://google.com";`

If you can use the request module though, then that would be better since it is more lightweight.

Comment: Resetting the same url to contentURL property doesn't reload the page.

Comment: you'd have to add a random piece to the url in that case like `?x=1239`